# Host smooth PhotoPrism server on low-end Android

Tags: server, artificial-intelligence, photo

I want to host a [PhotoPrism](https://www.photoprism.app/) Server on Android but have no experience in it.
I'm ready to root the phone but don't want to soft brick it by changing root files.
My android has Snapdragon 626 octa-core , 3GBs of ram and 32 GB storage
My phone is - [10 or G](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B0711T2L8G/ref=twister_B075V9FX4K?_encoding=UTF8&th=1)
Please help me with an guide to install the server and make it run smooth.

Thanks in advance.

I've tried searching for guides or tutorials but couldn't find any.